# Creating methods that will get average of arrays? Whats wrong with code?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I need help with creating methods that will get the average of OrderSize, see [this](http://prntscr.com/69bcdg) link.

The code is saying that the is no variable but as you can see there is.. any help is greatlyappreciated.

Comment: You cannot declare variable in one method and access it in another. You're doing that in your code.

Comment: Yep, must be another one of those compiler errors. Please read up on scope: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Comment: It is preferred that you post code here on this site instead of adding a link to some other site

Answer (score 2):

Since you declared the OrderSize variable inside the method main, that variable cannot be accessed outside of method main.  Move the OrderSize variable outside the method, so it is a member of the class; then it can be accessed from any method in that class

```
public class Array
{
  int[] OrderSize = {...};

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ..
  }

  public static double getAverage(int[] array)
  {
    ..
  }
}
```